# How to override generating XML from a hash?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a hash like this:

```
{
  12776=>["Item", "01:Antique", "fabric"], 
  12777=>["Item", "02:Priceless", "porcelain"], 
  12740=>["Item", "01:Antique", "silver"]
}
```

And I would like to generate XML like:

```
<items>
  <item type="01:Antique", material="fabric">some other attribute</item>
  <item type="02:Priceless", material="porcelain">some other attribute</item>
  <item type="01:Antique", material="silver">some other attribute</item>
</items>
```

Please demonstrate how this is possible.

Comment: You say you've been unable to succeed, but we can't tell what you've tried. Add code showing your attempt so we can help you correct it, don't expect us to write a solution for you, that you then have to force-fit into your code.

Comment: You'll have to write code to do it.  Try writing it yourself.  If it doesn't work, and you can't figure out why, then you can ask us.

Comment: I would like to see some examples of how this problem would be tackled by those who know. I've tried many things, lots of trial and error and can/will not post them here. I find your comments unhelpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely recommend using a gem like Nokogiri to do that for you.  Something like this should work:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new
xml.items do
  hash.values.each do |item_array|
    xml.item(type: item_array[1], material: item_array[2]) #some_other_attribute
  end
end
```

Which renders this XML:

```
1.9.3-p484 :019 > puts xml.to_xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>
  <item type="01:Antique" material="fabric"/>
  <item type="02:Priceless" material="porcelain"/>
  <item type="01:Antique" material="silver"/>
</items>
```

Comment: +1 for using `nokogiri`..

Comment: Thank you. I shall try this out. It looks just like the code I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This looks about right:

```
require 'nokogiri'

hash = {
  12776 => ["Item", "01:Antique", "fabric"], 
  12777 => ["Item", "02:Priceless", "porcelain"], 
  12740 => ["Item", "01:Antique", "silver"]
}

xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new
xml.items do
  hash.each do |key, (_, _type, material)|
    xml.item(type: _type, material: material) {
      text "some_other_attribute"
    }
  end
end

puts xml.to_xml
# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <items>
# >>   <item type="01:Antique" material="fabric">some_other_attribute</item>
# >>   <item type="02:Priceless" material="porcelain">some_other_attribute</item>
# >>   <item type="01:Antique" material="silver">some_other_attribute</item>
# >> </items>
```

- Hash's `each` sends the key/value pair into the block.
- Using `(_, _type, material)` assigns each of the value's elements to the variables.
- `_` is a black-hole variable (not really, but it's sufficient to think of it that way for this use), and swallows the value passed to it; Effectively, it means "ignore that".
- I used `_type` to avoid potential confusion with `type`. Ruby would be happy with it, but I wouldn't be.

The rest should be pretty self-evident.

Comment: This is a great explanation and it shows me some example code I would not have thought to try. Thank you. Unfortunately I have accepted the simpler looking solution above as I found it more readable and will hopefully be somewhat easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty raw implementation. You may try some XML library such as Nokogiri to manipulate XML generation, if needed.

```
hash = {
  12776=>["Item", "01:Antique", "fabric"], 
  12777=>["Item", "02:Priceless", "porcelain"], 
  12740=>["Item", "01:Antique", "silver"]
}

puts "<items>"

hash.sort_by{|k, _| k}.each do |_, array|
  puts %{  <item type="#{array[1]}" material="#{array[2]}">some other attribute</item>}
  # or maybe the following?
  #puts %{  <item type="#{array[1]}" material="#{array[2]}">#{array[3..-1].join(" ")}</item>}
end

puts "</items>"
```